# How to populate ComboBoxes by lines of a string Array?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, combobox

Please, what is wrong here

```
abc = labGuns.Text;  // multiline label
string[] arr = Regex.Split(abc, "\r\n");
x = 0; 
foreach (string line in arr)
{
    MessageBox.Show(line); //works fine - shows each line of label
    x = x + 1;
    string abc = "cbGuns" + x.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(abc); //works fine - shows "cbGuns1", "cbGuns2"...
    foreach (Control c in panPrev.Controls)
    {
        if (c.Name == abc) // five combos named cbGuns1, cbGuns2...
        {
            c.Text = line; //doesn't work. No combo changes its text
        }
    }
}
```

If I change last line to - `c.Text = "323"` - also nothing happened.
So, mistake is obviously somewhere near the end of code.

This code also works (as test):

```
foreach (Control c in panPrev.Controls)
{
if (c.Name == "cbGuns1")
{
c.Text = "323";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to add a line to a Combobox, not select a line currently in it, correct? In order to do this, you don't set the Text value of the Combobox to a string, you need to add a new ComboboxItem to the Combobox, like so:

```
c.Items.Add(line);
```

instead of

```
c.Text = line;
```

Let me know if this works!

EDIT:
Ok, since you're trying to change the selected item of the Combobox, I would just write

```
c.SelectedItem = line;
```

Comment: each line is in fact a combo item. I want to change SelectedItem

Comment: @Buena: then you aren't populating the ComboBoxes at all, because they're already populated.

Comment: Oh, in that case, then you'll want to edit the SelectedItem property. If you instead use C.SelectedItem = line, that should work. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: but I have another code (on btnClick) which can change ComboBox.Text normally

Comment: btw System.Windows.Forms.Cotrol has no dafinition for SelectedItem

Comment: Can we see the code for btnClick? I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish now...

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. Try setting a breakpoint and stepping through, to make sure line and abc are actually what you think they are.

Comment: Sean, yes,I see, the value of abc is not what it should be. I changed the way I populate the combos, This problem is solved, but another appears ::)), but i will ask in another question. AnyWay, ThanksVeryMuch.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. I'm guessing it's because you have two variables named abc in the code snippet you provided, one from earlier in the program and one you declare in the snippet.

Answer (score 2):

If your controls are combo and you want to set the 'Text' property without having a list of items then your combo should have the `DropDownStyle = DropDown`

Answer (score 1):

Try to cast c to DropDownList

```
DropDownList ddl =(DropDownList) c;<br/>
ddl.Text ="your text"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `c.Text = line;` with `c.Items.Add(line);`.

`AddRange` is preferred when adding multiple items, however, so instead of your `foreach` loops, try this:

```
foreach (Control c in panPrev.Controls)
{
    if (c.Name.StartsWith("cbGuns"))
    {
        c.Items.AddRange(arr);
    }
}
```